# Meta data location of modelling-views

Tags: metadata, storage, hana

I'd like to read meta data about our calculation views. (In order to do some best practice checks)

The check I want to make include:

- View is a graphical calculation view
- View-properties:

  - Default Client: Cross Client
  - Execute in SQL Engine
- Filter on columns (show if some column names appear)
- Read commends (we have a rule which states that each calculation view must have a commend in the semantics, which explains the purpose of the view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible by querying the _SYS_REPO tables.
I gave a full example answer here https://answers.sap.com/questions/58460/meta-data-sorage-location-of-modelling-views.html?childToView=59915#answer-59915

Comment: _SYS_REPO.ACTIVE_OBJECT column CDATA contains the XML Definition of the calculation view (For those who do not have a S-User ;)

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenNiehues for including the answer here. BTW: even without an S-User the SAP community can be accessed. It's even open for anonymous readers ;-)